# How to initialise select2 onto a different element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have my HTML structure as below.

```
<div id="a"></div>
<select id="b">
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option>bbb</option>
  <option>ccc</option>
</select>
```

And after I initialise **select2** with `$('#b').select2();` my DOM structure changes to,

```
<div id="a"></div>
<select id="b" data-select2-id="b" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
  <option data-select2-id="2">aaa</option>
  <option>bbb</option>
  <option>ccc</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 93px;">
  //
  // Child elements created by select2
  //
</span>
```

Whereas, I need the newly generated `<span>`and it's child elements to be placed inside the `<div id="a"></div>`

An easier way would be appending the `<span>` after initialisation, using `$('#a').append($('.select2-container'));` but I'm curious to know if **select2** provides an option within their plugin to achieve the same.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/rNVNvbe)

Comment: Why would you wanna do that? Cant you just place the select in the div a like <div id="a"><select></select></div>

Comment: @Grumpy - Working with a framework which doesn't provide much flexibility with the element structure.